# Javascript mixes memory addresses? (Resetting An Array does not work)

Tags: javascript

I have already solved this problem but it required an O(N) solution. It also seemed liked my solution was not taking the real situation into account. Can anyone explain why this happens?

In a simple program that I am writing (tic tac toe game),
I have a "destructor" function which resets all variables when the game is reset.

In particular, I have a two "global" variables (I'm aware of block scoping).
I set up one of these as a pseudo static variable to reset a "gameboard".

```
var board = [11,12,13,21,22,23,31,32,33];
```

I use this to keep track of occupied spaces on the board.

Now, when I restart the game to destruct the function I use a pseudo static variable that I initialized in as.

```
var staticBoard = [11,12,13,21,22,23,31,32,33];
```

So board gets updated while staticBoard is used to reset board in a function like this.

```
function destructor(){
   board = staticBoard;
};
```

This works fine for the first few iterations of the game, but later on board would fail to update, and would remain the same regardless of how many times I tried the destructor.

I tried this.`board = []; board = staticBoard;`.
But I would get the same result.
Eventually, I thought that javascript was somehow mixing up the memory addresses of the two variables, so instead of setting them equal toe ach other I did this.

```
function destructor(){
board = [];
staticBoard.forEach(function(element){
   board.push(element);
});
```

This worked and the problem stopped.

Can anyone please explain this, and also show a better solution if possible?

Comment: you aren't copying the array, you are only copying the reference.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you’re not copying any data when you do `board = staticBoard`, you’re simply assigning a reference to the *same* array. Simply illustrated:

```
xs = [1,2,3]
ys = xs
ys[2] = 4
xs //=> [1,2,4]
```

Instead you should either:

- Shallow-copy the array with [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice): `board = staticBoard.slice(0)`
- Assign to a literal array: `board = [11,12,13,21,22,23,31,32,33]`

You may want to use [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to prevent `staticBoard` from being able to be mutated at all (but note that mutations won’t error, just will fail silently):

```
xs = Object.freeze([1,2,3])
ys = xs.slice(0)
xs[2] = 4
ys[2] = 5
xs //=> [1,2,3]
ys //=> [1,2,5]
```

However, shallow-copying and freezing only works well because the arrays contain numbers, which are immutable. It doesn’t work as well if the contents are mutable:

```
xs = Object.freeze([[1]])
ys = xs.slice(0)
ys[0][0] = 2
xs //=> [[2]]
ys //=> [[2]]
```

Comment: Is this only for arrays? I'm assuming that many other data structures also do this.
I'm surprised that this is the first time i've run into this problem.

Comment: @Greg Variables in JS (and most langs) are always a reference and never copy the value. Even `const` won’t stop this, because that’s still about the *reference*, not the actual value. If the value is immutable you never change (mutate) the value itself, so it doesn’t matter. But for mutable values, you’ll see this. In JS, undefined/null, booleans, numbers, strings, symbols are all immutable; using `Object.freeze` makes an object (recall that arrays are just a type of object in JS) immutable (but not any objects it refers to, as seen above).

Comment: From my understanding, if you use the assignment operator to assign one variables value to another variable, you are passing it by value.
Passing it by reference only happens when you use a pointer, or you specifically state this condition in a function parameter.
eg. referenceFunction(int & param);
Otherwise, (as far as I know),  when you create a new variable you are creating an entirely new memory address. 
JS seems to take the variale on the left and make it a pointer to the right. However, this doesn't always happen.
Are you sure it's not some weird quirk of JS?

Comment: It’s not a quirk of JS. This behavior is the same in C, Java, Ruby, Python, and others. “Pass by reference” has nothing to do with this behavior, as there’s no function call. This is simply that variable assignment is the assignment of a *reference* to a value, and assignment does not copy the value.

You say “this doesn’t always happen”, however variable assignment always acts the same. Can you provide an example where it doesn’t happen? I suspect that in such a case, really it’s that the value is immutable, so the issue never arises.

Comment: I just tested this in python and got this:
'>>> testarray1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> testarray2 = testarray1;
>>> testarray2[2] = 10
>>> testarray1
[1, 2, 10, 4, 5]
>>> testarray2
[1, 2, 10, 4, 5]'

I find it incredibly difficult to believe that i've gone through almost 2 years of programming and never committed this to memory.
Probably because I learned to copy python lists by using the slice operator.
eg.
x = y[:] and I never assign it otherwise.

Comment: But as another example in python:
>>> num1 = 2
>>> num2 = 3
>>> num1 = 5
>>> num1
5
>>> num2
3
Pretty standard behavior there.
That is not passing by reference, it is passing by value.
Also, array/list copying is done in other languages either with brute force (for loop) or by explicitly declaring an array type or using a library function. (where it all probably happens behind the scenes).

However, not all languages assign "primitive" values by reference as a default.  (As shown above).

Are you saying that every value (language agnostic)  is passed by reference by default?

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re trying to show with your second example, as you’re just assigning number literals. But, as stated earlier, assignment isn’t what’s changing, it’s that numbers are immutable. If arrays were immutable, you wouldn’t see the behavior illustrated either, but that doesn’t suddenly mean variables aren’t storing a reference.

Comment: With the numbers example, there are two separate locations stored .
a location for num1 and a memory location for num2.
num1 = num2

Comment: I just looked up this concept, and it is a quirk of JS and python.
https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600

Here is a link that also explains the same concept in Ruby (A language I don't know).
https://launchschool.com/blog/references-and-mutability-in-ruby

It seems like we were both converging to the same point but in different ways. I was confused because I have mostly learned on non-interpreted languages. (Java C++). Learn something new everyday!

Comment: That JS article makes a weird example of `++`, which is defined in the spec as being `x = x + 1`, but the article seems to try selling it as being similar to `Array.push`, which it’s not (the latter has no assignment). The `++` operator disguises a variable assignment in most languages, which makes it misleading. I wouldn’t describe the overall behavior as a quirk of a language, simply a fact of having mutable operations on data structures. Interpreted vs. compiled has nothing to do with it, either. You can do the same in Java and C.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, object variables are essentially *pointers to memory locations*. When you do

```
obj1 = obj2
```

you're only assigning the *memory location* of `obj2` to `obj1` - the object in memory does not get copied. You should make a copy of the array instead, which does create a *new* object:

```
function destructor(){
   board = staticBoard.slice(0);
};
```

This way, the object located at `staticBoard` never gets mutated, so you can reference it over and over to get a new clean copy of the original board.

You can also use the `forEach` method, as you found, but that's a bit ugly; `slice(0)` is much more concise.

Comment: Is this only true for arrays?

Comment: It's true for any object, any non-primitive; arrays, objects, HTMLElements, any instantiation, functions, etc. Their variables all essentially reference the underlying object's *memory location*.

Comment: Thank you, I did a little more research on the subject. (After I received answers on here), and it seems as though this concept is not language agnostic.